# Antlr graphical rule representation

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Is there a tool to create a graphical representation of one's antlr4 grammar that means the parser/lexer rules e.g. as a graphical representation of a finite state machine?

It should be the case that it can be represented since it has backus naur form.

Example:

```
plus: INT '+' INT | plus '+' INT
INT: [0-9]+
```

A corresponding finite-state machine would be

```
start -> INT <-> plus
          |
          v
        exit
```

There may also be other graphical representations but a finite-state machine. The goal is to provide a different perspective in order to make debugging/understanding the grammar easier.

Comment: BNF doesn't have a clear representation "as a tree".   Would you care to provide an example of what you want?

Comment: Of course you are right. It could be graphically represented as automaton.

Comment: as a finite state machine

Comment: @Waschbaer: That goes for the lexer only - most grammars cannot be represented as a finite state automaton (only _regular_ grammars can, and once you do things like unlimited-depth nesting, your grammar is no longer regular).

Comment: If other folks are confused by reading this question and its comments, it is because OP changed the word "tree" with "finite state machine" in his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this: https://github.com/bkiers/rrd-antlr4. These types of graphics are called railroad diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use ANTLRWorks 2.1. There's a view called "Syntax Diagram" included that can generate railroad diagrams of your parser rules **and** your lexer rules.

I'm using those images for my master thesis and the process works fine so far.